# WP Где правильно делать сортировку? В php или mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Есть такая задача - произвести запись в базу данных кастомной таблицы WordPress значения элементов json (~1500 строк)
Элементы собираются через php функцию

```
function submitCollectedData($data)
{

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'sports_viewer_clear';

    $toInsert =  array(
        'id_json' => $data['header']['id'],
        'scheduled' => $data['header']['scheduled'],
        'type' => $data['header']['type'],
        'virtual' => $data['header']['virtual'],
        'sport_id' => $data['header']['sport']['id'],
        'sport_name' => $data['header']['sport']['name'],
        // ...
    );

    $wpdb->insert($table_name, $toInsert);

}
```

Есть желание, что б в БД писались уже отсортированные строки по параметру `'sport_id'` в связи с чем и интересуюсь, как правильно это делать ? Производить сортировку в php, а потом выполнять [insert](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb-insert) что бы значение `id` у таблицы которое формируется `id INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` было верным, или же сначала надо писать в Базу данные, а потом производить, как-то [ORDER BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) ?

Comment: Правильно сортировать даннные при **извлечении их из БД** в необходимый момент и с помощью ORDER BY соответственно

Comment: Операций на извлечений будет в 100 раз больше чем на перезапись данных в указанной таблице. Зачем делать 100 сортировок, если можно один раз сохранить уже отсортированные данные, и получать чистые данные ?

Comment: — Здравствуйте, вы специалист, скажите, как правильно? ...... —  Вот так правильно..... —  Я не согласен!!

Comment: Из 2-х предложенных Вы выбрали 3-й которого вообще не было в координатах.  Можно привести какую-то аргументацию своего ответа?  Или это из разряда - "я так делаю, дед делал, и вам советую."

Comment: Сегодня нужна одна сортировка, завтра другая, послезавтра третья, а может и вообще по двум или трём столбцам. Каждый раз будете переделывать? .......Если из таблицы будут удалены некоторые данные, то последующая вставка может быть произведена не в конец таблицы - и тогда либо всё перемешается, либо надо заново всё пересчитывать. Аналогично, если  придётся добавить в середину данные - придётся всё пересчитывать.

Comment: При извлечении данных обычно запрашивается небольшая порция, а движок БД с полями int на сортировку хорошо работает. .... Получается , условно, SELECT на 50 записей с сортировкой и **КАЖДЫЙ РАЗ ПЕРЕСЧЁТ 1500 или 100000 ЗАПИСЕЙ ПРИ ВСТАВКЕ НОВОЙ ЗАПИСИ В СЕРЕДИНУ** .....так себе оптимизация...... также не стоит забывать, что вставку надо производить в транзацкции... и блокировке, что повышает время вставки.

Comment: "Из 2-х предложенных Вы выбрали 3-й которого вообще не было в координатах"  ---- я вижу это так: "- Как правильно себе выколоть глаз: ножом или вилкой?  - Правильно не выкалывать себе глаз....- Я не согласен"

Comment: Вот спасибо, теперь понятно, что если мы не контролируем последовательность в которой будут вставляться/убираться данные из таблицы, то это имеет смысл. --- Лично мне больше нравиться пример: Пришел в библиотеку попросить книги Толкиена, -> библиотекарь бегает перебирает всю библиотеку, пока не найдет нужного автора (и так на каждый запрос), вместо того что б пойти по алфавиту и взять книгу из полки где храняться книги на букву "Т".

Comment: @BlackStar1991, комментирую твой второй коммент: если напрягает при извлечении, то на это у ВП есть кеширование (причём на нескольких уровнях)/трансиенты. Не говоря уже за редис и прочие мемкеши.

Comment: Теперь о глобальном. Никто тебе не запрещает **при первичном** заполнении таблицы записать в желаемом порядке. Для хранения данных это не имеет никакой роли. И ещё надо знать, что ID в ВП - это сквозной суррогатный ключ.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 не совсем корректный пример с библиотекой, т.к. выборка идёт не всех записей сразу, а, как правило, части из них..... эта самая часть, как правило выбирается по id (в данном случае id_json) - а это **уже и есть те самые А, Б, В, Г** и т.д. в библиотеке.... sport_id - это уже доп. сортировка к уже запрошенной и выбранной группе..... так что тому же библиотекарю в данном случае надо сбегать взять книги на А, Д, Ж, М, Н (что равно id), а затем их всё равно сортировать по, например, по названиям книг среди выбранных (что в данном случае sport_id)

Comment: *Есть желание, что б в БД писались уже отсортированные строки по параметру 'sport_id' в связи с чем и интересуюсь, как правильно это делать ?* Совершенно бессмысленное действие. Данные в таблице всё равно физически будут располагаться в том порядке, который задаёт первичный ключ таблицы. Что забавно - далеко не факт, что потом они будут извлекаться в таком порядке, если не задать явно сортировку в запросе. А поскольку `sport_id` - не первичный ключ, то записи будут "пересортированы" уже в момент сохранения в таблицу.